# Error: "Excel cannot open the file 'xxx.xlsm' because the file format is not valid." when re-opening a xlsm file with embedded VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button on my excel sheet with the embedded code below. Basically, I am trying to copy the sheet along with the embedded code since the sheet will be partially submitted, closed, re-opened, and then fully submitted.

The saveascopy function works perfectly in the PartiallySubmit function if I do not close the active workbook, but if I close the active workbook (ActiveWorkbook.Close) and then re-open it, I get the error in the Title (Error: "Excel cannot open the file 'xxx.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.") I'm wondering if I need to enable macros anywhere in the code before closing it so it does not malfunction when trying to re-open.

If I do not close the workbook in the Partially_Submit function, then the FullySubmit function works to save a copy and delete the old file. If I save the copy as a .xls, I am able to close and re-open it in compatibility mode. If I save the file as any other (.xlsx or .xlsm) I get the same error ("Excel cannot open the file 'xxx.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.")

```
Sub Partially_Submit()

    Dim Path, Filename As String


    Path = "\\aaa\bbb\ccc\"

    Filename = ActiveSheet.Name _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Date:", 
    LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="S/N:", LookIn:=xlValues, 
    Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="FRI#:", LookIn:=xlValues, 
    Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Move to New Workbook

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveSheet.Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & ".xlsm", 
    FileFormat:=xlNormal

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    **ActiveWorkbook.Close**

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Restore User View
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
        .DisplayHeadings = True
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub


Sub FullySubmit()

    Dim Path, NewPath As String, OldFile As String

    Path = "\\aaa\bbb\ccc\"

    Filename = ActiveSheet.Name _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Date:", LookIn:=xlValues, 
    Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="S/N:", LookIn:=xlValues, 
    Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="FRI#:", LookIn:=xlValues, 
    Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _
    & "_" _
    & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Completion Date:", 
    LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) _

    NewPath = "\\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd\"

    OldFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewPath & Filename & ".xlsm", 
    FileFormat:=xlNormal

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewPath & Filename & ".xls", 
    FileFormat:=xlNormal

    Kill OldFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple of a fix lol. I was looking into so many other additional codes to add and not even looking to change what I had. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems

```
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

instead of

```
FileFormat:=xlNormal
```

was adequate.